# UIView as a component over the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a view which contain a UITableView in the application which is displayed above the keyboard in its UIViewController when it's necessary.
Client ask to have the same implementation in other views.
In this case I have to use the same view in other classes.

I want to implement this functionality as a controller and call it when it is necessary from other classes in code.
I attach a screen capture and I evidentiate the tableview which will be the common element.

Can you, please, help me with some approach to do this like a component,
some examples ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.
Create a new class, subclass of UIView.
At the implementation you need to do smthng like this

```
- (id)initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){
       self.frame = frame;
       self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Don't forget to add this method to interface.
At the init method you can create all elements and logic of your view.

Now, wherever you need, you can add this class smthng like theese

```
MyViewClass *view = [[MyViewClass alloc] initWithFrame: frame (where it must be on your parent view)];
[self.view addSubview: view];
```

If you need to handle some actions from your custom you can use NSNotifications.

**UPDATE**

```
@interface PaymentView : UIViewController {
    MyCustomView *cView;
}
```

use `cView` instead `MyViewClass *view`. Now, when you need to remove your custom view, you can use:

```
[cView removeFromSuperview;]
```

Comment: Am how I'll remove this class when I finish job with it ?

Comment: Hello again, Related to the notification,I'll try to make a delegate method and check the result selected from table?Your opinion related to my proposal ?I suggested NSNotification i saw this aspect.